# about JVM heap argument -Xmx and -Xms

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        byte[] b = new byte[1024*1024*5];
    }
}
```

You see each operation allocates 5M. When I set `-Xms8M -Xmx8M`, it runs successfully without exception, while when `-Xms7M -Xmx7M`, it throws `OutOfMemoryError` exception. Could someone explain why? I'm under Windows 7, 64bit, Eclipse 4.3.
Following code is same result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] b;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        b = new byte[1024*1024*5];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistakenly assume that only 5MB of memory are allocated by that program, and you're wrong.
Just because you create a 5MB array doesn't mean there isn't additional memory used for classloading and other things.

So to answer your question, you're allocating too little memory for your process.

Comment: Thanks! Then is it possible to get how many memory each part used?

Comment: You can use a profiler to see what parts of a program use the most memory and CPU. You can try `visualvm` which is included with the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Because executing the program involves creating a ClassLoader, loading classes, instantiating the System OutputStream, etc. Those operations also need to allocate memory on the heap.